# Flask and Flask Restx application GET returns the API description instead of the function defined in a class

Tags: python, rest, flask, flask-restx

Currently creating a flask and flask-restx python project where im using the post and get functions in a class which inherits the "Resource" from flask-restx.

I first started with the "post" function which worked perfectly, but when implementing a "get" function, all that's returned is the api description that's created in the first api instantiation.

The following is the response from the GET request:

[The get request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vDIo.png)

And this is how the GET is implemented:

[GET implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAyNW.png)

As seen, the request doesn't even reach the function.

The POST works perfectly and is performing everything I defined in its function.

What could be happening?

I've tried putting different decorators on the get and also moving other logic into classes different from the resource one, even commenting the POST function leaving only the GET one.